# lightning:recordEditForm Need to send recordEditForm data back to Apex controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

I am new to Lightning and i have designed a component using recordFormEdit.
On the recordFormEdit handleOnSubmit action, i am sending the data back to object using the standard functionality(Without apex controller).

Now, the same form data now needs to be sent back to apex controller(as i have to perform another action using the data).

```
<lightning:button aura:id="GPV" label="Save and Send fax" type="submit" onclick="{!c.saveAndSendFax}"/>
```

I am having issue while accessing the form data. Is there any means to get field values of the form.
i have tried the below code for getting the values but it says undefined:

```
 var formValue=component.find("Form").get("v.value");
        console.log("form value",formValue);
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole code of your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get the form values using below piece of code:-

```
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
            event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
            var fields = event.getParam('fields');
            fields.Street = '32 Prince Street';
            component.find('myRecordForm').submit(fields);
        },
```

Basically, We are preventing the form getting submitted by default when user submit it via UI, and getting the Object Instance with values using **event.getParam('fields')** and you can access any field by using  **fields.your_field_api_name**, also you can modify it by assigning a value to it.

In the last, You need to resubmit the form using **component.find('myRecordForm').submit(fields)** so that records get saved.

If you want to send the data to apex controller, You can send the **fields** as parameter like this:-

```
var action = cmp.get("c.updateOpp");
        action.setParams({ opp : fields });
```

where your apex method is defined like this:-

```
@AuraEnabled public static void updateOpp(Opportunity opp){
//do something
}
```

Comment: .thanks... will try it and let u know